# MongoDB slow queries

Tags: mongodb

I have a really simple mongo query, that should use _id index.
The explain plan looks good:

```
> db.items.find({ deleted_at: null, _id: ObjectId('541fd8016d792e0804820100') }).sort({ positions: 1 }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 7,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [
            [
                ObjectId("541fd8016d792e0804820100"),
                ObjectId("541fd8016d792e0804820100")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "mydbserver:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

But when I execute the query it executes in 100-800ms:

```
> db.items.find({ deleted_at: null, _id: ObjectId('541fd8016d792e0804820100') }).sort({ positions: 1 })
2014-09-26T12:34:00.279+0300 [conn38926] query mydb.items query: { query: { deleted_at: null, _id: ObjectId('541fd8016d792e0804820100') }, orderby: { positions: 1.0 } } planSummary: IXSCAN { positions: 1 } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:70043 nscannedObjects:70043 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1 locks(micros) r:1391012 nreturned:1 reslen:814 761ms
```

Why is it reporting `nscanned:70043 nscannedObjects:70043` and why it so slow?

I am using MongoDB 2.6.4 on CentOS 6.

I tried repairing MongoDB, full dump/import, doesn't help.

**Update 1**

```
> db.items.find({deleted_at:null}).count()
67327
> db.items.find().count()
70043
```

I don't have index on `deleted_at`, but I have index on `_id`.

**Update 2 (2014-09-26 14:57 EET)**

Adding index on `_id, deleted_at` doesn't help, even `explain` doesn't use that index :(

```
> db.items.ensureIndex({ _id: 1, deleted_at: 1 }, { unique: true })
> db.items.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.items"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "deleted_at" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_1_deleted_at_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.items"
    }
]
> db.items.find({ deleted_at: null, _id: ObjectId('541fd8016d792e0804820100') }).sort({ positions: 1 }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 7,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 8,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [
            [
                ObjectId("541fd8016d792e0804820100"),
                ObjectId("541fd8016d792e0804820100")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myserver:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

**Update 3 (2014-09-26 15:03:32 EET)**

Adding index on `_id, deleted_at, positions` helped. But still it seems weird that previous cases forces full collection scan.

```
> db.items.ensureIndex({ _id: 1, deleted_at: 1, positions: 1 })
> db.items.find({ deleted_at: null, _id: ObjectId('541fd8016d792e0804820100') }).sort({ positions: 1 }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_1_deleted_at_1_positions_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [
            [
                ObjectId("541fd8016d792e0804820100"),
                ObjectId("541fd8016d792e0804820100")
            ]
        ],
        "deleted_at" : [
            [
                null,
                null
            ]
        ],
        "positions" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myserver:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: Did you make an index on the field `deleted_at`? You can do a test on `db.item.find({deleted_at:null}).count()` to compare with `70043`.

Comment: I updated my question with the counts

Comment: Why are you using sort, when the number of scanned entries should be at max 1, since you are filtering based on id which is unique?

Comment: The sort part is generated using mongoid ruby gem. Without the sort part it works fast.

Comment: I have a model

    class Item
      include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Paranoia
      self.default_scoping = -> { where(deleted_at: nil).asc(:positions) }
    end

Comment: I went through the docs some more, and I believe I have more clarity now. We are expecting that the find() will filter the results, and then the sort would apply on the filtered set. Apparantly, mongo does not process the query that way.I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Abhishek Pathak, waiting for your update. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. The query planner should select the `_id` index and the `_id` index should be all you need as it must immediately reduce the result set to one document. The sort should be irrelevant as it's ordering one document. It's a weird case because you are explicitly asking for one document with an `_id` match and then sorting it. You should be able to go around mongoid and drop the sort as a workaround.

.explain() does not ignore the sort. You can test that simply like so:

```
> for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { db.sort_test.insert({ "i" : i }) }
> db.sort_test.ensureIndex({ "i" : 1 })
> db.sort_test.find().sort({ "i" : 1 }).explain()
```

If MongoDB can't use the index for the sort, it will sort in memory. The field `scanAndOrder` in explain output tells you if MongoDB cannot use the index to sort the query results (i.e. `scanAndOrder : false` means MongoDB can use the index to sort the query results).

Could you please file a bug report in the [MongoDB SERVER project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER)? Perhaps the engineers will say it's working as designed but the behavior looks wrong to me and there's been a couple of query planner gotchas in 2.6.4 already. I may have missed it if it was said before, but does the presence/absence of `deleted_at : null` affect the problem?

Also, if you do file a ticket, please post a link to it in your question or as a comment on this answer so it's easy for others to follow. Thanks!

Comment: By intuition, the `.explain()` should include `.sort()`. But really the manual just states it makes the judgement. Otherwise, I don't think the example you provided above is able to prove `.explain()` apparently include `.sort()`. My reason is, by the result the questioner provided, because the number of documents after index query is only one, so `sort` operation is unnecessary. The `scanAndOrder` should be `false`, but it's `true`. Why? I guess `.explain()` just makes a judgement regardless of final result from query.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE :** *corrected my answer that suggested to use a (_id, deleted_at) compound index.Also in the comments, more clarity on how explain() might not reflect the query planner in certain cases.*

What we are expecting is that `find()` will filter the results, and then the `sort()` would apply on the filtered set. However, according to [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort) doc, the query planner will **not** use the index on `_id`, and also the index (if any) on `postion` for this query. Now, if you have a compound index on `(_id, position)`, it should be able to use that index to process the query.

The gist is that if you have an index that [covers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries) your query, you can be assured of your index being used by the query planner. In your case, the query definitely isn't covered, as indicated by `indexOnly : false` in the explain plan.

If this is by design, it deifinitely is counter-intuitive and as [wdberkely suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26062503/647952), you should file a bug report, so that the community gets a more detailed explanation of this peculiar behaviour.

Comment: I tried adding `id, deleted_at` index, doesn't help, see **Update 2**

Comment: Does it really have to scan the full collection and not the resultin set that was filtered with `find`? With previous versions of mongodb I didn't have this problem.

Comment: About your statement `It ignores the sort() part` during `.explain()` operation, could you share some official or solid proof about that? Thanks.

Comment: @na43251, I was wrong in suggesting that an (id, deleted_at) index would help, see my updated answer for a better explanation. It does scan the full collection instead of the filtered set in specific cases. I believe this is arising because the query planner now also uses index intersection, which either by design or as a bug, uses indexes in a counter-intuitive way.

Comment: @Wizard, we observe a discrepancy between the explain() and plan summary for the same query.In explain(), n, nscannedObjects and nscanned all are 1. However, the plan summary says that 70043 objects are being scanned in the actual query. Additionally if you look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#behavior, particularly the 2nd paragraph, we can draw the conclusion that explain() in this case at least, is ignoring how sort() will affect its use if indexes.

Comment: I don't think the 2nd paragraph is clear enough to prove that `.sort()` will be ignored during `.explain()` running even though it's possible. Additionally, after I read your updated answer above, I think you may make a mistake on the comprehension of `Index Intersection` - the manual says there is no intersection between tow separate indexes when the first one is used to query only but not the sort part, but it doesn't say both indexes do not join the query. Actually index `{qty:1}` joins the query. You can test it.

Comment: Another point, index should be mostly used to narrow scanning range. If the number of documents is very small after indexing, `scanAndOrder` turns out a piece of cake. Otherwise, the cost of cover-the-query is relatively high, it's not the point at this question, in my opinion. Anyway, thank you for sharing the answer, it let me think over further. :)

Answer (score -2):

I am guessing that you have 70043 objects with id of '541fd8016d792e0804820100'.  Can you simply do a find on that id and count() them?  Index does not mean 'unique' index -- if you have a index "bucket" with a certain value, once the bucket is reached, it now does a scan within the bucket to look at every 'deleted_at' value to see if its 'null'.  To get around this, use a compound index of (id, deleted_at).

Comment: _id in mongodb is a special, unique index analogous to a primary key in relational databases. There cannot be a index "bucket". Infact, as far as I know, there are only compound or haystack indices in mongodb, no buckets.

Comment: I have 1 document with id 541fd8016d792e0804820100

Comment: @na43251, Could you make a test on `db.items.find({ deleted_at: null, _id: ObjectId('541fd8016d792e0804820100') }).hint({_id:1}).sort({ positions: 1 })` before creating that compound index you've made? If still scanning so many documents, I think it's a bug!

Comment: Yes, `hint` helps, I have downgraded to 2.6.3, looks like the problems are gone, but I will monitor this closely, maybe this issue comes up after some load.